# archive command failed with exit code 1

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

WAL files are not archiving to archive location, even space is available on mount point.

Please find below errors.

cp: write error: No space left on device
2021-11-29 11:27:08.672 UTC [3725060] LOG: archive command failed with exit code 1
2021-11-29 11:27:08.672 UTC [3725060] DETAIL: The failed archive command was: cp pg_wal/000000010000096B00000011 /home/ericsson/Backup/postgresql/pgbackup/wals/000000010000096B00000011

Please can any one provide the solution for this issue..

Comment: Your claim "space is available" contradicts the error message "no space left on device". I am inclined to believe Postgres here. Probably the backup path is on a different mount point than where you think it is.

Comment: Yes backup is happening on separate mount point